# Flex Repeater Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, flex3, repeater

In my application I'm using a canvas and repeater inside HBox it is Dynamic,..now I want to keep a `horizontal scrollbar` for the same,  I may display more than 50 canvas addresses inside that Hbox and repeater.

Here is my code:

```
<mx:HBox id="addrBox" x="42" y="161" width="1000%" styleName="ContextPanel"  resizeEffect="resize" horizontalGap="5" height="0" paddingLeft="15">
    <mx:Repeater id="rpt" maxWidth="1000" dataProvider="{ customerAddress }"   >
        <mx:Canvas height="243" width="283" id="addressCanv"  cornerRadius="0" styleName="ContextPanel">
            <mx:Label id="seq" text="{rpt.currentIndex+1 }" x="99" y="0"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="address1" maxChars="50" change="address1_changeHandler(event)"  text="{ rpt.currentItem.addressOne}" x="99" y="60"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="address2" maxChars="50" change="address2_changeHandler(event)"    text="{ rpt.currentItem.addressTwo}" x="99" y="90"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="address3" maxChars="50" change="address3_changeHandler(event)"  text="{ rpt.currentItem.addressThree}" x="99" y="120"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="postalCd" restrict="[0-9]" maxChars="6" change="postalCd_changeHandler(event)"  text="{ rpt.currentItem.postalCode}" x="99" y="150" width="167"/>
            <mx:ComboBox id="cntryCdCmb"  prompt="Select" change="cntryCdCmb_changeHandler(event)" selectedIndex="{ StaticDataHolder.countryList.getItemIndex(ASUtil.getValue(StaticDataHolder.countryList,rpt.currentItem.countryCode))}" dataProvider="{ StaticDataHolder.countryList }"  x="99" y="180" width="167"/>
            <mx:CheckBox id="primaryFlag" label="isPrimary"  selected="{ (rpt.currentItem.primaryFlag == 0)?true:false }" change="primaryFlag_changeHandler(event)" x="19" y="210"/>
            <mx:Label x="10" y="0" text="Seq No"/>
            <mx:Label x="10" y="62" text="Address 1"/>
            <mx:Label x="10" y="92" text="Address 2"/>
            <mx:Label x="10" y="122" text="Address 3"/>
            <mx:Label x="10" y="152" text="Postal Code"/>
            <mx:Label x="10" y="182" text="Country Code"/>
            <mx:Label x="10" y="29" text="Address Type"/>
            <mx:ComboBox x="99" y="29" width="167"  prompt="Select" change="addTypeCmb_changeHandler(event)" id="addTypeCmb" selectedIndex="{ StaticDataHolder.addressTypes.getItemIndex(ASUtil.getValue(StaticDataHolder.addressTypes,rpt.currentItem.addressType))}" dataProvider="{ StaticDataHolder.addressTypes }"></mx:ComboBox>
            <mx:Label x="235" y="210" text="{ rpt.currentItem.primaryFlag}"/>
            <mx:Image id="delAddr" x="258" y="3" height="21" width="17" source="images/delete2.png" maintainAspectRatio="true" click="delAddr_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:HBox>
```

Kindly give some idea for getting horizontal scroll bar for the Repeater.

Comment: What does it happen when u add 50 child inside HBOX. The default property of hbox horizontalScrollPolicy is AUTO, hence the scroll bars will come automatically when the **One of the container's children extends beyond the left edge or right edge of the container**. So no need to Worry about that

Answer (score 1):

Add one more attribute to your `HBox` that is `horizontalScrollPolicy`

```
<mx:HBox id="addrBox" x="42" y="161" width="100%" styleName="ContextPanel" 
resizeEffect="resize" horizontalGap="5" height="0" paddingLeft="15" horizontalScrollPolicy="on">
```

You can set the values `on`, `off` and `auto`. By using `auto`
HScrollBar will be visible if contents does not fit in the given space.

Comment: @Aravinth You have given `width="1000%"` instead `width="100%"` please check that also...

Comment: No its not working the scroll bar is visible..but i cant able to click the scrollbar

Comment: @Aravinth If Hscrollpolicy set to on Hscrollbar always display if contents fitt into the HBox scrollbar disabled if contents exceed the with of HBox scrollbar will be enabled. so bettr to use `auto`. Otherwise dont use horizontalScrollPolicy property because As  Sudharsanan  said "The default property of hbox horizontalScrollPolicy is AUTO"

Answer (score 1):

`<mx:HBox id="addrBox" x="42" y="161" width="100%" styleName="ContextPanel" 
resizeEffect="resize" horizontalGap="5" height="0" paddingLeft="15" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">`

horizontalScrollPolicy auto gives the best result if it reduces from 50.